# Angular. TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, subscribe

I am getting this error: TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

[image]

Comment: The return type of `httpService.getGameDetails` is `void`.

Comment: @mchedlo - you should add here the getGameDetails function in your httpService. Ideally as a code snippet, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of `httpService.gameDetails` to the object that you created called `Game` instead of `void`, also return the response. I think it's implicitly marking as void becase you won't be returning anything in your gameDetails method.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add '**return**' somewhere here, probably in front of '**this.gameSub**'